# Adding target to UIButton without @objc reference

Tags: uibutton, swift5

When we make a UIButton programmatically and add a target for its click action.
And for the selector we need a function with "@objc" reference, even if we are working in a purely swift project.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let requiredButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 30))
    self.view.addSubview(requiredButton)
    requiredButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapAction(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
}

@objc func buttonTapAction(sender:UIButton) {
    // button action implementation here
}
```

Is there a way to do this without the "@objC" reference???

Comment: There is no pure Swift project if you deal with `UIKit`. All `NSObject` subclasses including the target/action pattern are based on Objective-C

Comment: Is this the same in SwiftUI too???

Comment: Please don't mind, i don't even know if there is a component like UIButton in switUI. Just heard of it. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you target iOS 14+ there is new API that you can use without "@objc" references:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let requiredButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 30), primaryAction: .init(handler: { _ in
        // button action implementation here
    }))
    self.view.addSubview(requiredButton)
}
```

If you target iOS 13+ you can build UI using SwiftUI with Button controls. SwiftUI is currently internally based on UIKit, but you can write whole apps in swift using SwiftUI without a single "@objc" reference

Comment: do you have documentation for this? I'm not sure what pattern to search for more info

Comment: @mjr https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3600349-init

Answer (score 0):

UIButton is a foundation object from NSObject subclass so it executes on the Objective-c runtime, so you need to tell Swift to expose the code to objective-c

Reference: https://craiggrummitt.com/2016/09/16/any-vs-anyobject-vs-nsobject-in-swift-3/

Comment: so can we expect this dependency of UIKit removed in subsequent swift versions??

Comment: Swift is open source so it's decently possible, only time will tell, found GH page: 
"Although inspired by Objective-C and many other languages, Swift is not itself a C-derived language. As a complete and independent language, Swift packages core features like flow control, data structures, and functions, with high-level constructs like objects, protocols, closures, and generics. Swift embraces modules, eliminating the need for headers and the code duplication they entail."

[https://github.com/apple/swift]